# Scanning for SMBGhost vulnerability

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability-scanners, scan, nessus, openvas

I am a university student currently trying to demonstrate exploitation of the SMBGhost Vulnerability on Windows 10 (Version: 1903, Build Number: 18362.356). I need to provide evidence that the vulnerability exists. However when using Nessus (Community Edition) within my Kali Linux environment. The vulnerability does not get detected, however when using a SMBGhost Scanner on github it says my Windows 10 host is vulnerable. Please can I get advice as to how to configure my Nessus in order for it to show that the SMBGhost vulnerability exists.

I have attached screenshots of my current results from Nessus and Windows 10 Version. [image: Windows 10 Version][image: Current Results from Nessus]

Comment: Your task mandates that you *have* to use Nessus?

Comment: I don't have to use Nessus but tools that have a GUI where I can take a screenshot of all the vulnerabilities identified.

Answer (score 1):

The Nessus plugins that cover CVE-2020-0796 (SMBGhost) are [listed here](https://www.tenable.com/cve/CVE-2020-0796/plugins).
You need to add "Basic Network Scan" with "Credentials" as scan type; do look into [this discussion](https://community.tenable.com/s/question/0D53a00006rL6QzCAK/scan-for-smbghost-vulnerability).

There's also a Metasploit module `exploit/windows/local/cve_2020_0796_smbghost`, which requires a session. More details [here](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/13187).

I would go with a [Nmap scan](https://github.com/psc4re/NSE-scripts#cve-2020-0796) first:

```
nmap -p445 --script cve-2020-0796 <<target>>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution has not worked. Could you provide specific setup instructions for the scan.

Comment: @MahinChowdhury may I know the Nessus version? Also, please be resourceful in that understand how a Nessus scan detects vulnerabilities. For a vulnerability to get detected, respective plugin needs to be part of the scan. It all boils down to whether the Nessus version supports it, if so what scan type and plugin group to include.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am using Nessus Community version 10.1.2 on Kali Linux (version 2022.1) and the plugins that it has available for the vulnerability is 134420,134421,134428. I used it on a Advanced Network Scan and I did not deselect any plugins